# Azure DevOps Repository Deploy Token possible?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-repos

Is it possible in Azure DevOps to create a "ReadOnly Deploy Token" for a repository?

Practically, to access the repository in a "ReadOnly" mode with a url, eg:

```
https://deploy:myDeployToken@dev.azure.com/myCompany/myProject/_git/main
```

We want to link a [Private Azure DevOps Repository as a `composer` repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/authentication-for-private-packages.md#manual-inline-http-basic).

[GitLab has such a feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/group_access_tokens.html) that looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to create a personal access token with `Code (Read)` scope for a user that only has access to that specific repository.

Or register an ssh key for a user that only has read access to that repository.

There are no repository scoped tokens in Azure DevOps that you can easily generate.

What you can do, is kick off a pipeline and steal its token (for the duration of the pipeline), you *can* set the desired permissions for those. But that's an OAuth token that will expire after a short time.

There should be an API to generate such OAuth tokens, but that's no available from any UI and those tokens have a relatively short life.

Comment: In your first sentence, do you mean a PAT for a *user* that only has access to that specific repository?

Comment: Yes. A specific user who's token you use.